# How do you completely remove a nested object from all documents in a mongodb collection?

Tags: mongodb

Say I want to remove the *secrets* nested object:

```
{
    "_id": "2xhjMSEocFNLrKhXj",
    "name": "Jane Doe",
    "secrets": {
        "codename": "assasin",
        "ssn": "123-45-6789"
    }
}
```

I want to remove this nested object from all documents.  The documents should then look like this:

```
{
    "_id": "2xhjMSEocFNLrKhXj",
    "name": "Jane Doe"
}
```

I found lots of examples about removing array elements but not nested objects.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
db.getCollection('my-things').updateMany({},
    { $unset: { "secrets": { _id: "secrets" } }}
);
```